# Hijri and Gregorian date convert method some time not working in ngx-hijri-gregorian-datepicker

Tags: angular, hijri

I used ngx-hijri-gregorian-datepicker with angular 8. But Hijri and Gregorian date convert method some time not working.

This is my code sample. In constructor

```
private dateFormatterSev: DateFormatterService
```

In my function

```
     if (this.Date1) {
        let Date1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.Date1));
        if (this.selectedDateType === DateType.Hijri) {
            Date1 = this.dateFormatterSev.ToGregorian(Date1);
        }
        req.date1 = Date1.year + '-' + Date1.month + '-' + Date1.day;
    }
    if (this.Date2) {
        let Date2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.Date2));
        if (this.selectedDateType === DateType.Hijri) {
            date2 = this.dateFormatterSev.ToGregorian(Date2);
        }
        req.date2 = Date2.year + '-' + Date2.month + '-' + Date2.day;
    }
```

In above code first method work and give correct result for req.date1. But second method not working and give null result.
( **req.date2 = null-null-null** )
This .ToHijri(date) method work. But this .ToGregorian(date) method some time given null object.

Comment: please post example runs where it fails and passes, showing the data that fails and passes, and how it fails/passes

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like you have a 'd' instead of a 'D'; I just now posted the details in the Answer box (ignore the '^' chars -- I edited those out, but that change might be pending).

Comment: please correct question.  also, add some debug code to display failing values

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
date2 = this.dateFormatterSev.ToGregorian(Date2);
```

to

```
Date2 = this.dateFormatterSev.ToGregorian(Date2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But still same

Answer (score 0):

you could make your own service such that you use the global `Intl` object instead of external library. it is very simple as following:

```js
a = new Date();
localeFormat= 'ar-SA-islamic-umalqura';
Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeFormat).format(a)
```